# PHP fortunes script

Tags: php, arrays, file

I'm currently writing fortune-like submodule for my larger PHP project and my question is why it it's not working properly. (Also, I'm looking for more suitable ways to do that)

file.php

```
<?
$file = file_get_contents("pytania.txt", true);
$number = substr_count($file ,"##")-1;

preg_match_all("/##(.*?)##/si", $file, $matches);

for($i=0;$i<$number;$i++){
echo($matches[1][$i]."<br><br>");
}
?>
```

pytania.txt

```
##
System operacyjny to zbiór programów, które:
a. Obsługują wyłącznie klawiaturę, mysz i monitor
b. Zarządzają pracą komputera
c. Wykonują obliczenia matematyczne
d. Wczytują programy zewnętzne do pamięci komputera
e. Porządkują dane zapisane na dysku
##
Na pulpicie systemu Windows nie można znaleźć:
a. Ikony
b. Kosza
c. Skrótu do aplikacji
d. Paska menu
e. Paska zadań
##
Aplikacja to inaczej:
a. Folder
b. Program
c. Pamięć komputera
d. Pulpit
e. Dysk
##
```

The main problem I'm experiencing that the second (2/3) fortune isn't even displayed. Any clues? Ideas?

Comment: Why use regular expressions?  Just use `explode`.

Comment: followed your idea. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
<?
$file = file_get_contents("pytania.txt", true);
$number = substr_count($file ,"##")-1;

$a = explode('##', $file);

for($i=1;$i<=$number;$i++){
    echo $a[$i]."<br><br>";
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively use a `foreach()` loop. (<sup>*Which I think suits this better*</sup>)

```
$file = explode('##', $s);

foreach($file as $item) {
    echo $item . "<br /><br >";
}
```